# Just calling in to complain

Tags: c, gcc

About C. Mind you, I *love* C - I do everything in it. But just now I encountered this gem:

```
// opening a file and expecting a certain size of it.
unsigned char buf[ sizeof(sometype) ];
struct stat s;
//.. open file, do fstat
if (s.st_size != sizeof(buf)) {
}
```

And I get a warning from GCC: Comparing signed and unsigned. So sizeof() (gcc) returns a different type than s.st_size (libc).

Sorry about the complaint. I got a few beers in me and I encountered this and it is simply infuriating: they should both be unsigned.

Comment: `s.st_size` field is of type `off_t`, to be compatible with offsets type (for `fseek`, etc...), so it is signed, sorry.

Comment: While I agree, this isn't a question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is blatantly not a question.

Comment: This rant hides a genuine question: *what is the best way to get rid of the compiler warning?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a POSIX consistency issue than a C problem:

- The `st_size` member of the `stat` structure is the file size expressed in bytes and has type `off_t`, out of consistency with other POSIX functions that use a (potentially negative) byte offset into a file.
- This type is signed and although it does not make much sense to have a negative file size, a negative value could indicate that the file size cannot be computed.
- The main issue regarding this member is its range: it used to be a 32 bit long and this caused headaches when files larger that 2GB or even 4GB became more common.

`gcc` is warning about potential signed / unsigned comparisons because the semantics of such expressions are obscure to many people, underwent subtle changes in the course of normalisation and produce potentially counterintuitive results.

In your case, I am sure you are well aware you can get rid of the warning by casting one of the other arguments, but you should beware that `off_t` and `size_t` might have different sizes, and they do in 32-bit environments, so casting `s.st_size` as `(size_t)` is incorrect:

```
if (s.st_size != (off_t)sizeof(buf)) {
}
```

You might argue that `off_t` might be smaller than `size_t`, but it is unlikely.  In any case, there is a way to avoid the cast, if `gcc` does not complain about mixing signed and unsigned expressions in simple arithmetics, you can write:

```
if (s.st_size - sizeof(buf) != 0) {
}
```

Finally, disabling the warning would be counter productive as it is usually a good hint about a real problem.  Using all the help you can get from the compiler by turning on most warnings (`gcc -Wall -W` or `clang -Weverything`) is a good habit.

Comment: The thing is: where I work, I have to compile with -Wall and -Wextra. Also, any cast is seen as a red flag (apart from the fact that they are ugly). As is any warning. So, I'm stuck with this one, and under normal circumstances I wouldn't be so riled up about it, but these two are so close to C itself that it just makes my hair stand on end. Why would st_size by signed? Who thinks up a design like that?

Comment: @KJH: `st_size` is signed, because it is of type `off_t`, it being the type used for file sizes (as opposed to `size_t` which is the type used for sizes in memory, as well as the type of the value the `sizeof` operator yields); because `lseek()` uses `off_t` for the new position, either relative or absolute to current position in bytes, `off_t` must be a signed type. One could argue (I would) that it would've been better to have `soff_t` for `lseek()` -- analogous to `ssize_t` and `size_t` --, but this is what we have right now.

Comment: @KJH: I suspected something like that. Does the above trick compile without warnings?  You could also use `ssizeof(buf)` if it is defined in a standard header on your target system.